# Date format on Google Sheets; last change script

Tags: google-sheets

I'm creating a cell to mark when this spreadsheet was "last changed".

My code is below:

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if( r.getColumn() == 2 ) { //checks the column
    var row = r.getRow();
    if( row == 3 || row == 4) {
      var time = new Date();
      time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-04:00", "MM/DD/yy, hh:mm:ss");
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B24').setValue(time);
    };
  };
 };
```

However, when it updates it, it produces, "06/167/15 03:35:50". This makes some sense since when I last updated it, it was 6/16/2015 3:35:50 PM. Why is the date three digits and what does that mean?

Also, I have a cell which is a "summary" of all numbers, where it sums up all numbers in the spreadsheet. I am using this a way to determine if any number on the sheet was changed since if any number is changed, this "summary" cell will be changed, as well. However, if I change any other cell, the "summary" cell changes (due to the formula), but my script does not update the time. It appears to do so only if I actively change that cell, ie. change the formula. Any way to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

User lower case "d".  Currently:

```
"MM/DD/yy
```

Change to:

```
time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT-04:00", "MM/dd/yy, hh:mm:ss");
```

Capital "D" returns the number of days that have elapsed in the year.

[Date and Time Patterns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

For your other problem, try using an installable on change trigger:

[Google Sheets Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events)